# If $\tan{\frac{x}{2}}=\csc x - \sin x$, then find the value of $\tan^2{\frac{x}{2}}$.

Tags: trigonometry

> If $\tan{\frac{x}{2}}=\csc x - \sin x$, then find the value of $\tan^2{\frac{x}{2}}$.

HINT: The answer is $-2\pm \sqrt5$.

What I have tried so far:
$$\tan{\frac{x}{2}} = \frac{1}{\sin x}-\sin x$$
$$\tan{\frac{x}{2}} = \frac{1-\sin^2 x}{\sin x}$$
$$\tan{\frac{x}{2}} = \frac{\cos^2 x}{\sin x}$$

I don't know how to solve this problem. Pls help. Thank you :)

Comment: Let $u=\frac x2$.

Answer (score 4):

Notice that
$$
\cos(x) = \frac{1 -\tan^2 (x/2)}{1+\tan^2(x/2)}
$$
And that
$$
\tan^2(x/2) = \frac{\cos^4(x)}{1-\cos^2(x)}
$$
Let $t = \cos(x)$. Plug the 2nd equation into the first one and after some algebra, we get
$$
(1-t)(1-t^2-t^4) = 0
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\cos^2x=\tan\dfrac x2\sin x=\dfrac{\sin\dfrac x2}{\cos\dfrac x2}\cdot2\sin\dfrac x2\cos\dfrac x2=2\sin^2\dfrac x2=1-\cos x$$

$$\implies\cos x=\dfrac{-1\pm\sqrt5}2$$

As for real $x,\cos x\ge-1,\cos x\ne\dfrac{-1-\sqrt5}2<-1$

Using [Weierstrass Substitution](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/algebra/WeierstrassSubstitution.shtml) $$\dfrac{1-\tan^2\dfrac x2}{1+\tan^2\dfrac x2}=\cos x=\dfrac{-1+\sqrt5}2$$

Now apply [Componendo et Dividendo](https://www.qc.edu.hk/math/Junior%20Secondary/Componendo%20et%20Dividendo.htm)

Comment: Please find the updated answer. Please feel free to pinpoint any mistake/doubt

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use that $$\frac{1}{\sin(x)}-\sin(x)=1/2\,{\frac {1+ \left( \tan \left( x/2 \right)  \right) ^{2}}{\tan
 \left( x/2 \right) }}-2\,{\frac {\tan \left( x/2 \right) }{1+ \left( 
\tan \left( x/2 \right)  \right) ^{2}}}
$$